# css circle look messed in custom radio controller

Tags: html, css

I designed a custom radio box with simple css. But its middle circle wont show correctly in browser 100% view. I zoomed the browser viewport to 250% and its shows correctly. Why is that?

[100% view wrong look. not look like a circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5MOe.png)

[250% middle circle looks as a circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rkoI.png)

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

html {
  font-size: 14px;
}

body {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.custom-control {
  display: none;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.radio+label::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.radio+label::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: .5rem;
  top: .5rem;
  width: .4rem;
  height: .4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.radio:checked+label::after {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="custom-control radio" name="radio" id="radio1">
<label for="radio1">Female</label>
<input type="radio" class="custom-control radio" name="radio" id="radio2">
<label for="radio2">Male</label>
```

Comment: That's interesting. I noticed that if I changed the width and height to 6px instead of .4rem the issue goes away but it doesn't explain why it happens with rems. After playing around with it some more, I converted the width and height to .438rem, which is 7px based on 16px body font, and the issue also goes away. It just might be rendering weirdly at that .4rem width and height and it needs it to be another size to render correctly.

Comment: @pavger yeah with pixel values of width and height no problems. But with ems and rems values give those shape messy looks.

Comment: Have you tried using .438rem instead of .4rem?

Comment: @pavger .438rem is working. but why? why is the problem with .4rem and with some values?